# How to refer to selected items in ListBoxChecked in MaterialSkin.2 nuget?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my winforms app in form I inherite MaterialFrom from MaterialSkin.2 nuget - package from google.

I create ListBoxChecked with some items. I would like to do some opeartions in selected items, but I can not find any instruction how can I refer to those items.

In Windows Form I would use probably `checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices`, but in MaterialForm this instruction doesnt exist.

Does anybody know what is the right instruction for this operation ?

I was looking for answer, but can not find any similar topic.

EDIT:

Okay. Found a solution for my problem. If anybody in the future will have same or smilar problem I inform you that MaterialListBoxChecked as same as MaterialListBox don't support this operation. In that case you have to use `for` loop.

Example:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= MaterialListBoxChecked.Items.Count; i++)
    
            {
                if (MaterialListBoxChecked.Items[i].Checked)
                {
                    checkedItems.Add(MaterialListBoxChecked.Items[i].Text);
                }
            }
```

Comment: If this is the [MaterialSkin.2 NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialSkin.2/2.3.1#show-readme-container) you referring to, you should not be using it. There's also a warning in the GitHub page. It also doesn't really work in .NET5+ (where, in the port to .NET, the Control you mentioned has been removed, BTW) -- I've removed the references to Google's MaterialDesign because it's not really related

Comment: Is there any different design for winforms ? I would not write my own js/css frontend. I prefer use something that exists already, because I have a lot of work in applications business logic ?